# SQL: Combine result columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT Category, SUM (Volume) as Volume 
FROM Product 
GROUP BY Category;
```

The above query returns this result:

```
Category    Volume
-------------------
Oth          2
Tv Kids      4
{null}       1
Humour       3
Tv           5
Theatrical   13
Doc          6
```

I want to combine some of the columns as one colum as follows:

- Oth,{null}, Humour, Doc as **Others**
- Tv Kids, Tv as **TV**
- Theatrical as **Film**

So my result would look like:

```
Category    Volume
-------------------
Others       12
Tv           9
Film         13
```

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a CASE here, like this:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN Category IN ('Oth','Humour','Doc') 
    OR Category IS NULL THEN 'Others'
    WHEN Category IN ('Tv Kids','Tv') THEN 'TV' 
    WHEN Category = 'Theatrical' THEN 'Film' 
  END as category , 
  SUM (Volume) as Volume 
from Product 
GROUP BY 
  CASE 
    WHEN Category IN ('Oth','Humour','Doc')
    OR Category IS NULL THEN 'Others'
    WHEN Category IN ('Tv Kids','Tv') THEN 'TV' 
    WHEN Category = 'Theatrical' THEN 'Film' 
  END;
```

Null must be dealt with outside the `IN` list as it is a special value.

Comment: You'll have to put your query in a cte or a derived table and then do a `GROUP BY`. right now it will show Others - 4 times,TV  -2 times

Comment: @ughai I am pretty new to this stuff, so I am really not sure what you want me to do.

Comment: @Thanos Markou I get the same result as before, not the expected result.

Comment: @TauseefHussain - The comment was directed towards Thanos Markou :)

Comment: Assuming {null} means null and not a string '{null}' you need to modify the first `WHEN` clause to cope with nulls. Otherwise it's OK.

Comment: @mjsqu Here null isnt a string. However with the above code i get `{null}` in my result set.

Comment: **PLEASE!** `CASE` is really awful. You can do much better with a separate table which holds the categories.  See the answer from @ThorstenKettner below. *(PS: I never downvote)*

Comment: @SQLPolice THe las edit from mjsqu gives me exactly what I need. Not sure why you find it awful.

Comment: @TauseefHussain It works, but it is really not like a database is meant to work. You would be far better off if you created a 2nd table which holds different categories, and you link them. Then you would not need such a complicated case statement, just a very small group statement of 2 lines.

Comment: @SQLPolice Noted that Sir :)

Comment: @TauseefHussain You are welcome ;) By the way, it's called *database normalization*. If you have time, then look for some articles or books. You will see, it pays off, really. *(BTW, I **never** downvote)*

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use a `case` statement to group categories together.

```
select case category when 'Tv' then 'Tv'
                     when 'Film' then 'Film'
                     else 'Other'
       end as Category,
       sum(Volume) as Volume
from  (
          SELECT Category, SUM (Volume) as Volume 
            FROM Product 
           GROUP BY Category
      ) subcategoryTotals
group by Category
```

(I think most DBs will allow you to group by the alias `Category`. (If not you can re-use the case statement)

**Edit:** Just a final thought (or two):

You should consider normalizing your database - for example, the `Category` column should really be a foreign key to a `Categories` table.

Also, this sql is reasonably ok because the `case` statement isn't too long or complex. If you wanted to split things up further it could quickly get to be unmanageable. I'd be inclined to use the idea of categories and subcategories in my database.

Comment: **HELP! PLEASE!** `CASE` is really awful. You can do much better with a separate table which holds the categories.  See the answer from @ThorstenKettner below. *(PS: I never downvote)*

Comment: To be fair, I did suggest database improvements - I was just trying to answer the OPs question given his/her current DB model.

Comment: Oh yes that's right, now I see the edit. -- Oh yes, and this is the only "good" solution. The solution with `case` is long and hard to maintain; and the effort is better invested in quickly setting up a new table.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution might be to implement those groups in the database. For instance:

**category_group**

```
id_category_group  name    sortkey
1                  Others  3
2                  TV      2
3                  Film    1
```

**category**

```
id_category  name        id_category_group
1            Oth         1
2            Tv Kids     2
3            Humour      1
4            Tv          2
5            Theatrical  3
6            Doc         1
```

**query**

```
SELECT g.Name, SUM (p.Volume) as Volume 
FROM Product p
LEFT JOIN Category c ON c.Id_Category = p.Id_Category
LEFT JOIN Category_Group g ON g.Id_Category_Group = c.Id_Category_Group
GROUP BY g.Id_Category_Group, g.Name
ORDER BY g.sortkey;
```

This makes NULL a group of its own, though. But well, it *is* a group of its own, as NULL means not known (yet), so you don't actually know whether it's TV, Film or Other. If you still want to count NULL as Others, change the ON clause accordingly:

```
LEFT JOIN Category_Group g 
  ON g.Id_Category_Group = COALESCE(c.Id_Category_Group, 3) -- default to group 'Others'
```

Comment: @SQLPolice: It actually depends. If this grouping is an ad hoc idea and might not be needed again, why not quickly write a query with a CASE construct. I've done this myself every now and then. But once I see that these groups are somewhat substantial and needed more often, I would definitely introduce them in my database.

Comment: well yes, but then, it happens so often that something "improvised" becomes permanent ...

Answer (score 1):

Try following,

```
select category_group , sum(volume) as Volume from
(
SELECT 
    Category, 
    Volume, 
    case 
        WHEN Category IN ('Oth','Humour','Doc','{null}') THEN 'Others'
        WHEN Category IN ('Tv Kids','Tv') THEN 'TV' 
        WHEN Category = 'Theatrical' THEN 'Film' 
    end as category_group
FROM Product 
) T
group by category_group
```

Comment: **OH LORD!** You too come up with `CASE` ? This is really awful. You can do much better with a separate table which holds the categories.  See the answer from @ThorstenKettner below. *(PS: I never downvote)*